# Excel VBA - exit for loop

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I would like to exit my `for` loop when a condition inside is met. How could I exit my `for` loop when the `if` condition has been met? I think some kind of exit at the end of my `if` statement, but don't know how that would work.

```
Dim i As Long
For i = 1 To 50
    Range("B" & i).Select
    If Range("B" & i).Value = "Artikel" Then
        Dim temp As Long
        temp = i
    End If
Next i
Range("A1:Z" & temp - 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
```

Comment: `If [condition] Then Exit For` inside your loop

Answer (score 374, accepted):

To exit your loop early you can use `Exit For`

`If [condition] Then Exit For`

Comment: @nixda Please remove your comment, as the hyperlink you shared points to VB.NET documentation, not Office VBA documentation. VBA's `Exit` statement has fewer options than VB.NET's. In fact, VBA only supports: `Exit Do` `Exit For` `Exit Function` `Exit Property` and `Exit Sub`. VBA has no `Exit While`. The correct link is: [Office VBA Reference -Exit statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/exit-statement)

Answer (score 30):

Another way to exit a For loop early is by changing the loop counter:

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If i = 5 Then i = 10
Next i

Debug.Print i   '11
```

---

```
For i = 1 To 10
    If i = 5 Then Exit For
Next i

Debug.Print i   '5
```

Comment: Assign a loop counter is much less robust and future proof than explicitly exiting the loop. The former can be broken by a change in the loop counter's maximum as the code is modified if the editor doesn't notice it's also being used elsewhere. It also doesn't apply to `For Each` loops.

Comment: This is simply another solution to the question specific to the `For` loop (not `For Each`). Pro’s and con’s apply to different solutions and different situations - for example this is a more robust format than the `Go To label` which brakes the logic (non structured programming), or a possible workaround of the `Continue` keyword, missing in VBA. The merits of `Exit For` can be questioned as well if the logic doesn't perform proper cleanup of objects - bad implementations are not quite relevant here though (@jpmc26)

Answer (score 1):

The first answer given with the following is indeed i.m.o. best practice:

```
if i = 0 then exit for
```

However, this is also an option:

```
Sub some()

Count = 0
End_ = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B1047854").End(xlUp).Row

While Count < End_ And Not ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Count).Value = "Artikel"
    Count = Count + 1
    If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("B" & Count).Value = "Artikel" Then
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("A1:Z" & Count - 1).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    End If
Wend

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

if condition (inside your while - loop) then goto (some marker outside the loop)

Comment: It's a possible solution and probably not the best practice. To be avoided if not necessary in your particular circumstances.