# Excel: how to paste "values" to first blank cell?

Tags: excel, vba, cell, copy-paste

Considering that I have already read through another thread explaining "how to paste to first blank cell"... [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19768954/excel-how-to-paste-to-first-blank-cell?newreg=9010f88a006f4dd29f26556ea6ccb437)
I need to know how to paste "value".
Example:

```
 Dim sh As Worksheet, tCell As Range
 Sheets("Lunch Extend").Range("B4:F31").Copy
 Set sh = Sheets("Backup")
 Set tCell = FreeCell(sh.Range("B3"))
 sh.Paste PasteSpecial xlValues tCell
```

However, the last line does not read correctly.  Any help?

```
sh.Paste tCell
```

...works, but I need  values.  Thanks.

Adding FreeCell function here...

```
Function FreeCell(r As Range) As Range
' returns first free cell below r
  Dim lc As Range     ' last used cell on sheet
  Set lc = r.Offset(1000, 0).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
  Set FreeCell = lc
End Function
```

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect for the Sheet.PasteSpecial method, but it would probably be simpler to use the Range.PasteSpecial method.  See VBA Help for the proper use of these methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `FreeCell` is a function you wrote and that it works.  Try this:

```
Dim sh As Worksheet, tCell As Range
  Sheets("Lunch Extend").Range("B4:F31").Copy
  Set sh = Sheets("Backup")
  Set tCell = FreeCell(sh.Range("B3"))

  tCell.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues
```

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you very much for your help.  I wish I could vote, but sadly I cannot.  However, you're ability to understand my question and answer it so precisely is not only appreciated but is very impressive.