# For each cell in range if cell is negative then change color

Tags: vba, excel

I'm pretty knew to VBA and I'm trying to check if in the specific range of column M if there's a negative number and if it is to change the font to red. This is only working for the first number in my report. I have a feeling that I made a small mistake so please let me know.

```
Sub Format_M_Column()

    Range("M:M").Select
    With Selection
        Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Value = .Value
    End With

    For Each cell In Range("M:M")
        If cell.Value < 0 Then
            cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
            Exit For
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: custom format of `0.00;[Red]-0.00` will do it without the need for vba

Comment: I know but I'm trying to make this vba because it'll include other things for my report.

Comment: @ScottCraner okay now i see from Peh's example that it could be used  in vba. This saves a lost of space. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as ScottCraner pointed out this should be all you need and should be **much faster** without that loop.

```
Sub Format_M_Column()
    With Range("M:M")
        .NumberFormat = "0.00;[Red]-0.00"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove `Exit For`. It exits the for - loop:

[Excel VBA - exit for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414969/excel-vba-exit-for-loop)

Comment: omg thanks! I was following an answer in this thread and it mentioned to keep it. I'm guessing i wasn't understanding correctly why that specific person had to keep it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code (May be faster than yours)

```
Sub Format_M_Column()
Dim rng As Range
Dim cel As Range

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns(13))

    With rng
        .NumberFormat = "0.00"
        .Value = .Value
        For Each cel In rng
            If cel.Value < 0 Then cel.Font.ColorIndex = 3
        Next cel
    End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```