# Exit for loop to prevent overwrite

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I used Exit For as suggested in [Excel VBA - exit for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9414969/excel-vba-exit-for-loop) to fix the overwrite. I am getting Next without For error on Next j line, which is the second line to the end.

```
For i = 2 To lastrow

    For j = 99 To 167 Step 6

        If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 2))) Then

            Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
            Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed

            Exit For


            If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 8))) Then

                Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)

                Exit For

                If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 14))) Or _ 
(Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 20))) Then

                    Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                    Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow

                    Exit For


    Next j

Next i
```

Comment: You are missing three `End If` statements to conclude your `If` blocks

Comment: Or construct an `If...ElseIf` statement..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code with `ElseIf` statement

```
Sub test2()
    For i = 2 To lastrow
        For j = 99 To 167 Step 6
            If (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 2))) Then
                Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = vbRed
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbRed
                GoTo NextLine
                'Exit For
            ElseIf (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 8))) Then
                Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = RGB(146, 208, 80)
                GoTo NextLine
                'Exit For
            ElseIf (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 14))) Or (Not IsEmpty(ActiveSheet.Cells(i, j)) And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, j + 20))) Then
                Cells(i, 2).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                Cells(i, 3).Interior.Color = vbYellow
                GoTo NextLine
                'Exit For
            End If
        Next j
NextLine:
    Next i
End Sub
```

Instead `Exit for` I use `Goto NextLine` to avoid overwrite. Don't know if this work because don't know how to test the code. Please let me know if is clear enough or you need more help.